# (swiper/react) Custom Navigation with useRef isn't working correctly

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HmB3.gif)

Trying to custom navigation, and then applying style was complete, but actually there's problem clicking is not working sometimes.

Code:

```
export const CustomSwiper: FC = ({
  children
}) => {
  const prevRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const nextRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  const swiperParams: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    navigation: {
      prevEl: prevRef.current ? prevRef.current : undefined,
      nextEl: nextRef.current ? nextRef.current : undefined,
    },
    loop: true,
  }

  return (
    <Swiper
      className={classes.container}
      {...swiperParams}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>

      <button type="button" ref={prevRef}>
        <Triangle />
      </button>
      <button type="button" ref={nextRef}>
        <Triangle />
      </button>
    </Swiper >
  )
}
```

**Expected behavior**:

Everytime click button swipers them left/right.

**Actual behavior**:

Sometimes works, but most time doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use UseRef, in the navigation prop

navigation={{
prevEl: '.prev',
nextEl: '.next',
}}

Just add **clickable: true**

navigation={{
prevEl: '.prev',
nextEl: '.next',
clickable: true,
}}

This just worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You don´t need to use useRef for this.
In the documentation nextEl and prevEl receive HTMLElement or string with CSS selector, so it could try something like this:

```
<Swiper
  navigation={{
   prevEl: '.prev',
   nextEl: '.next',
 }}
>
    <SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <div className="prev"></div>
    <div className="next"></div>
</Swiper>
```

In my case I did like this:

```
<div className='slider-wrapper'>
    <Swiper
      navigation={{
       prevEl: '.prev',
       nextEl: '.next',
     }}
    >
        <SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    
    </Swiper>
    <div className="prev"></div>
    <div className="next"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use ***useRef()*** Just import Navigation like this -

```
import { Navigation } from "swiper";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
```

Then use the module **Navigation** in your code and add the class to your button like this -

```
<Swiper
  modules={[Navigation]}
  navigation={{
     prevEl: '.prev',
     nextEl: '.next',
  }}
>
<SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
<SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>
<button className="prev"></button>
<button className="next"></button>
</Swiper>
```